# Select only users that are (at least) member in certain groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, report, exists

I been working on a query to get a users list with their respective groups.
I got that covered.
However there are some restrictions:

1. if The user is ONLY member of group5 it should not appear on the list
2. If is member of group5 and other groups it should appear on the list

I can get the users that are not members of group5 and if they are members, they don't appear on the list.

My problem is with users members of group5 and members of other groups, they do not appear but they should appear on the list

Here is the query:

```
select 
    user_id, group_id  
from 
    group_users 
where 
    group_id != 5 
    and user_id not in (select distinct user_id 
                        from group_users 
                        where group_id = 5)
```

E.g. user 1 and 2 should appear, they are members of group1, group2 and group5. Those users do not appear because the group5, and they should even if they the have other groups.

On the other hand user3 is member of group5 only, therefore, this user do not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you only want users that have at least one `group_id` which is `<> 5`:

```
SELECT user_id, group_id  
FROM   group_users gu
WHERE  group_id <> 5  -- optional, might help performance
   OR  EXISTS (       -- just this works, too
   SELECT 1 FROM group_users 
   WHERE  user_id = gu.user_id
   AND    group_id <> 5
   )
```

If you add more `WHERE` clauses wrap these two expressions in parentheses. Operator precedence.

Comment: Right, it helped me, now I understand more about SQL